# WPF Create polygon with corners?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm looking to create the following shape from image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvMTy.png) in XAML? I tried to do it with a polygon and made it, but I could not make the bottom corners.

Here is my code:

```
<Polygon Points="50,0 180,90 180,150 50,150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="91" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Margin="0,29,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Fill="Black"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a Polygon, use a Path with two arc segments for the round corners:

```
<Path Data="M50,0 L180,90 180,140 A10,10 0 0 1 170,150 L60,150 A10,10 0 0 1 50,140Z"
      Fill="Black"/>
```

For details see [Path Markup Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax).

Comment: Thank you. The bottom corners are now fine, but when I increase the width, the corners are stretched and not as in the picture. How can I make the corners well and with the desired width? I did not understand the Path control best..

Comment: If you increase the width or height and do not uniformly stretch the Path (i.e. by the same factor in both directions), the geometry is of course distorted. Set the desired size in the original path coordinates in the first place.

Comment: now it looks like this, but something is wrong
 `<Path Data="M0,29 L200,77 200,150 A10,10 0 0 1 150,150 L10,150 A10,10 0 0 1 0,140Z"
      Fill="Black" Width="200" Height="120"/>`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmrqD.png

How can I correct the right corner and background on the entire Path?

Comment: Don't set the Path's Width and Height (or at least make them large enough to show the whole geometry). Also make sure the start and end points of the arcs match their sizes.

Comment: Now the only problem is the right corner. Can you tell me where the problem is in the code ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFt8Y.png

`<Path Data="M0,29 L200,94 200,150 A10,0 0 0 1 10,150 L10,150 A10,10 0 0 1 0,140Z"
      Fill="Black" Margin="0,29,0,0" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Visibility="Visible" Stretch="Fill"/>`

Comment: Please make yourself familiar with how path markup works. There is online documentation available, and it's pretty simple.